# wine-platfom-runtime-core20-won't update

Tags: updates, wine, snap

I was served this update to complete.  It won't run with an error "cannot perform the following task::
...nothing more.  I installed Wine a long time ago with the intention of installing Virtual DJ for Windows on Ubuntu, but I haven't used it.  I uninstalled the app and purged the files at the CLI.  I'm still getting the update request and here are some further details:
"error: cannot perform the following tasks:

- Fetch and check assertions for snap "wine-platform-runtime-core20" (74) (cannot verify snap "wine-platform-runtime-core20", no matching signatures found)"

I've tried all of the online help but this one is a real puzzle.  How do I get this resolved?  Thank you.
DJS